# does using gzip on command line have the same result as using zlib programmatically?

Tags: gzip, zlib

I can compress a file using gzip on the command line or zlib programmatically. Are the created deflated files equal? I can live with different headers.

Also, what is the relation between gzip's compression factor (1-9) and zlib's parameters (level, window bits and mem level)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, they're not exactly equal, but both are compatible with either decompressor. In other words, gzip streams produced by either are interchangeable between them or with any other compliant decompressor.

zlib also has compression levels 1-9, which behave approximately the same as gzip's levels 1-9. The window bits and memory level parameters are not available on gzip, where those are fixed effectively at zlib's defaults. Those parameters both allow embedded zlib applications use less memory at the cost of reduced compression effectiveness.